How to fix an error deploying nestjs microservice app to the docker?
I am trying to put nestjs monorepo to the docker. I found this dockerifle:
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# development stage
FROM base AS development 
ARG APP 
ARG NODE_ENV=development 
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
RUN npm install
COPY . . 
COPY .env .
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npm run build ${APP} 

# production stage
FROM base AS production 
ARG APP 
ARG NODE_ENV=production 
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist 

# Add an env to save ARG
ENV APP_MAIN_FILE=dist/apps/${APP}/main 
CMD node ${APP_MAIN_FILE}

and this docker compose file
services:
  api-gateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - APP=api-gateway
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - cassandra
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app
      
  postgres:
    container_name: relaxee_postgres
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "relaxee"
      POSTGRES_USER: "root"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - app

  cassandra:
    container_name: relaxee_cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_USER=root
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra 
    networks:
      - app

  redis:
    container_name: relaxee_redis
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --requirepass root --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes: 
      - redis:/data
    networks:
      - app

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: relaxee_rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - app

volumes:
  backend:
  postgres:
  cassandra:
  redis:
    driver: local

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

After building localy, everything works fine. Building in docker, im getting folowing error after nestjs start.
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
I tried to check dependencies like libs and .env
